# How does sass @extend really work for "merging selector sequences"?

Tags: css, sass

I came across this when I was browsing through the sass document 
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#merging_selector_sequences
and this really throws me off. This is the example it uses:

```
#admin .tabbar a {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#demo .overview .fakelink {
  @extend a;
}
```

compiles to

```
#admin .tabbar a,
#admin .tabbar #demo .overview .fakelink,
#demo .overview #admin .tabbar .fakelink {
  font-weight: bold; }
```

I can get that the first two `#admin .tabbar a` and `#admin .tabbar #demo .overview .fakelink` should be generated, but the last one `#demo .overview #admin .tabbar .fakelink` really doesn't make sense to me as I thought @extend is supposed to make a copy of whatever selectors contains `a` and replace it with `#demo .overview .fakelink`.

What bugs me more is

> While it would technically be possible to generate all selectors that could possibly match either sequence, this would make the stylesheet far too large. The simple example above, for instance, would require ten selectors.

I don't understand how it came up with the number 10, even if you do all the combinations with the order of `#admin .tabbar` and `#demo .overview` maintained, it will only be 6:

```
#admin .tabbar #demo .overview .fakelink
#admin #demo .overview .tabbar .fakelink
#demo .overview #admin .tabbar .fakelink
#demo #admin .overview  .tabbar .fakelink
#admin #demo .tabbar .overview .fakelink
#demo #admin .tabbar .overview .fakelink
```

So I'm really concerned that I'm missing something serious regarding how @extend really works. I really appreciate if someone can help me clarify this stuff.

Comment: Not sure how they count up to ten; but `#admin .tabbar a` could be the 7th selector.

Answer (score 1):

Your general understanding of `@extend` is correct. To cite the summary from the [reference](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html):

> @extend works by inserting the extending selector [...] anywhere in the stylesheet that the extended selector [...] appears.

For example

```
#zoo .animal {
  color: red;
}

.elephant {
  @extend .animal;
}
```

compiles to

```
#zoo .animal, #zoo .elephant {
  color: red;
}
```

However, what we talk about here is a special case where a selector sequence extends a selector within another sequence. In such a case *merging* the sequences is required and there are many potential ways to do so. Instead of generating all possible combinations,

> Sass generates only selectors that are likely to be useful

and

> When the two sequences being merged have no selectors in common, then two new selectors are generated: one with the first sequence before the second, and one with the second sequence before the first.

#### How can this be useful?

Have a look at the following example:

```
/*
 * There are young animals, which are small.
 */
.animals .young-animals .animal {
  font-size: 12px;
}

/*
 * And there are older animals, which are a little bigger.
 */
.animals .old-animals .animal {
  font-size: 18px;
}

/*
 * Whenever I tell my kid a a bedtime story, its beloved teddy bear
 * will be an animal.
 */
#bedtime-story .teddy-bear {
  @extend .animal;

  &:before {
    content: 'roar!';
  }
}
```

From our understanding of how `@extend` works for simple cases, we would assume that the compiled output only contains

```
.animals .young-animals .animal,
.animals .young-animals #bedtime-story .teddy-bear {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

but this limits us in the markup to a structure similar to the following:

```
<div class="animals">
  <div class="young-animals">
    <div id="bedtime-story">
      <div class="teddy-bear">Winnie</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the additional selector in the compiled CSS

```
#bedtime-story .animals .young-animals .teddy-bear
```

we have the chance to use a potentially more suitable nesting like the following:

```
<div id="bedtime-story">
  <div class="animals">
    <div class="old-animals">
      <div class="dog">Pluto</div>
      <div class="chicken">Coco</div>
    </div>
    <div class="young-animals">
      <div class="teddy-bear">Winnie</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the example of the OP it is the almost the same: there could be a `#demo` system that includes an `#admin` section or there could be an `#admin` panel that includes a `#demo` part. In either case the `.fakelink` should look like `a`. I can just guess, but I think that from the given combination possibilites the ones that are considered *likely to be useful*, are most often those where you do not split the individual sequences as you probably wouldn't do so in your markup (thinking in modules).